# Working from home in Switzerland for a UK company without becoming a swiss 'resident'?

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, residency, working, switzerland

I am a Swiss citizen and have been in the UK for two years. I am now working from home for my company for the forseeable future.

I would like to continue to work for my current employer but from Switzerland so I can be closer to family. I want to be counted as a tax resident in the UK because this matters to my employer. How long can i stay in Switzerland and work from there without having to register as a resident?

Also, will this have any implications for my employer?

Comment: Let's get this straight: Are you saying that you want to live in Switzerland but pay taxes elsewhere? Yours is probably the first case in human history. ;-)

Comment: Haha, I agree, taxes would be lower in Switzerland but since I would like for my company that things change as little as possible I would prefer to pay in the UK. As far as I know I would need to pay the taxes anyway in the UK since the employer is there? I might be wrong though...

Answer (score 1):

This cases are always quite complicated and you better discuss it with a lawyer before making the decision.

Looking at this document from OECD it one may think that it would be without tax consequences up to 30 days:

- https://www.oecd.org/tax/automatic-exchange/crs-implementation-and-assistance/tax-residency/Switzerland-Residency.pdf

There may be other consequence than tax (ie. health insurance).